# How to get day of month in number format?

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, nsdateformatter

What I'm looking for is the day of the month, example 2, 5, 30 or 31.  In integer form, and not a string.  I'm not looking for a programmed date, but today's date in whatever local they are in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the above answers are bad ways to accomplish this. This is the right way:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = components.day;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d"];
NSInteger day = [[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
```

Comment: how can I get the day of the year e.g 10 April is the 99th day of the year 2018??

Answer (score 0):

Start with an `NSDate` then run it through an `NSDateFormatter`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may work :

```
NSDate *theDate;

// Set theDate to the date you want
// For example, theDate = [NSDate date]; to get today's date

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"d";
NSString *theDayString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
int theDay = theDayString.intValue;

NSLog (@"%d", theDay);
```

`theDay` contains the value you're looking for !